# jQuery UI - can droppables detect which draggable is interacting during events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a droppable with over(), out(), and drop() functions, which I want to behave differently if divs of class A and divs of class B are dropped on it. Let's say that the droppable should turn yellow if class A is hovered over it, and red if class B hovers over it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `over`, `out`, and `drop` callbacks each take parameters of `(event, ui)`. `ui.draggable` is the element that was dragged onto the droppable. So you could do:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass('classA') {
    }
}
```

Be sure to check out the [jQuery UI Documention](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: Thanks! I should have taken a closer look at the documentation, you're right.